# How to get Set.size() inside a @Query with CrudRepository

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data

I have the following code:

```
@Query("SELECT t FROM Track t JOIN t.artists a WHERE a IN (:artists) GROUP BY t HAVING COUNT(t) = 2")
public Track findByArtistIgnoreCase(@Param("artists") Set<Artist> artists);
```

It works with a fixed value for the COUNT (like 2), but I need to replace that with artists.size() so it'll only return the Track with all of the artists in the set (Track & Artist have a @ManyToMany relationship).

The only way I can make it work is to pass another @Param which would be the Set's size, but that seems counter productive considering I'm already passing the object itself.

Is there a way to get the size of that Set parameter in the Query, or get it directly in SQL (counting the in() items)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you think it is counter productive. You still will need to calculate it, so you can simply pass another `@Param`.

```
@Query("SELECT t FROM Track t JOIN t.artists a WHERE a IN (:artists) GROUP BY t HAVING COUNT(t) = :size")
public Track findByArtistIgnoreCase(@Param("artists") Set<Artist> artists, @Param("size") Integer size);
```

In my opinion it's just easier to go that way, without wasting time on not so important issue.

Comment: Yeah I guess I will have to go with this route. Just one correction: I think CrudRepository only accepts Long as a param for count so new Long(artists.size()) is another thing I'll have to be doing every time I call this method...